# GET single loop form data in hyperlink php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to update quantity as i fill the quantity field and click on update button. It works but it shows the form fields of each item in the loop and works for the last entry update only. Something like this.

> /EcommerceClient/index.php?page=cart&action=update&id=3&name=%09%0D%0ACool+T-shirt&color=blue&size=XL&quantity=4&id=4&name=HBD+T-Shirt&color=yellow&size=XL&quantity=900

In the above link it should only get the information associated with id=3 only because i tried to update the quantity of id=3.

[image: Cart update]

Here is my code. Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

**Code**

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="update"){

    $id=  intval($_GET['id']);
    $size = $_GET['size'];
    $color = $_GET['color'];
    $qty = $_GET['quantity'];
    $index = $id." ".$color. " ".$size;
if( isset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]) && isset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]['color']) && $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['color'] == $color && isset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]['size']) && $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['size'] == $size){

    $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['quantity']=$qty;

    print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);//It just shows me the last item array.
}
}
?>
<form class="product" method="get" action="index.php">
    <table>
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
         ?>
                <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $value['name'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="color" value="<?php echo $value['color'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $value['size'] ?>">


                   <td><?php echo $value['id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['price']?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['quantity']?><input type="text" name="quantity"  value="<?php echo $value['quantity'] ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo  $value['color'];?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $value['size']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo "$" .$value['price']*$value['quantity']. ".00"; ?>
                 </tr>

        <?php
            }
        }

        ?>
        <tr><td><button type="submit">Update</button></td></tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: `$index = $id." ".$color. " ".$size;`? You're using an array. don't build one using a complex key. why not `$_SESSION['cart'][$id][$color][$size]`?  far far easier and more efficient - now you can access everything much easier.

Comment: @MarcB i have done this because i can have multiple entries for the same id which are on the basis of the color and size selection.This is the reason i am storing the color size and id in an array. It should update the array with these values.

Comment: what if someone orders multiple orders of the same size and color, you'll have duplicate id's. Marc's right. bad idea

Comment: how does that change anything? explain how you'd (quickly) search for "blue" tshirts that are under id (say) 42? in my version `$_SESSION['cart'][42]['blue']`. boom done.in yours, maybe something like `preg_grep('/^\d+  blue /', $_SESSION['cart'])`

Comment: @Pamblam no! If some one orders the same size and color it just updates the quantity of the previous entry using  `color` & `size`. And if i select some other color and size it makes a new entry in my cart. This is simple quantity updater form. It works for the last entry quantity update but doesn't work for the first one.

Comment: @MarcB why is my form getting all the entries`GET` values?? why not only selected one. Please have a look at link i have given

Answer (score 0):

You can update the quantity by not posting or getting all the cart product. Either you can use simple JS to update the field value or use SESSION variable array to update data as @Marc B mentioned.